# chown -R www-data:www-data sets ownership to root

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, chown

#### Background

I have a BananaPi with Bananian, Apache2 and OwnCloud.
Plugged into the Banana Pi is a NTFS-formatted HDD that gets mounted via ntfs-3g.
I created five users on the system and there is a `.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` file inside the base-directory of the mounted partition, resulting in a UID/GID/SID mapping of the users and in automatically setting the `permissions` and `acl` options when the partition gets mounted. (www-data is not included in the UserMapping-file.)
This partition contains a directory `shares` for Samba-shares and a directory `owncloud/data`.
The owner of the whole owncloud-tree is root:root and permissions are 777.

#### Problem

In order for apache to access the data and owncloud to work, the `owncloud/data` directory has to belong to www-data:www-data. But if I try this:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /media/hdd/owncloud/data
```

the ownership gets set to root:root, whatever owner the files and folders had before. This also happens for a single file:

```
chown www-data:www-data /media/hdd/owncloud/data/owncloud.log
```

and for every other place on the HDD:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /media/hdd/shares/maximilian
```

But if I set the ownership to an arbitrary user, for example:

```
chown -R maximilian:maximilian /media/hdd/owncloud/data
```

it works perfectly fine!

Why can't I set the ownership to www-data then?

Comment: What does "id www-data" show?

Comment: uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) Gruppen=33(www-data)

Comment: I don't know whether you want to share the drive with Windows or not, but if you do, you might want to read http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/ for details on the UserMapping file works. If not, I suggest using the `permissions` or `acl` option while mounting instead of user mappings since it will make things simpler.

Comment: @Munir: Thanks for the link. I added the following line (adapted to my case) for a generic mapping of users for whom no explicit mapping is defined to the UserMapping-file as pointed out on that site: `::S-1-5-21-1833069642-4243175381-1340018762-10000` Now the chown works fine. By the way, OwnCloud still showed me "Cannot create "data" directory". The reason was missing execute permissions for others on the path to the data folder as pointed out [here](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=30314&sid=f497036b856ffbbe341a87534da02f2f).

Comment: @Munir: Furthermore, mounting the HDD with `permissions` also worked for the chown. Initially, my intention for using the UserMapping-file was to get data uploaded from Win machines to the shares folder via SMB to be owned by the acting user in Win instead of always root. It didn't work out, though. Anyway, I just wanted to know the reason for my problem at least. Now that it works, I can save myself the effort to add `-o permissions` to the `mount`-command every time. :-)

Comment: Looks like the problem was solved by fixing the UserMapping... Please post this as an answer, as that might be useful to others looking at this question later on!

Answer (score -2):

The command

> chown -R [user-name]:www-data /media/hdd/owncloud/data
>   Where [user-name] replaced by the name of user maximilian
>
> chmod -R 755 /media/hdd/owncloud/data

Will help out

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not. The first command did nothing as always and the second one removed the write permission for group and others as expected. Also executing the first command another time afterwards did nothing.

Comment: First You have to add user to group www-data? Then it may be possible.

Comment: adduser maximilian www-data

Comment: Or you should try all command from 'sudo' in beginning of every command if not running as root user

Comment: There is the user "www-data" inside the group "www-data". However, I temporary added "maximilian" to "www-data" with no effect.
And, of course, I am acting as root the whole time.

Comment: Try by removing from www-data and adding in other groups and execute commands by sudo

Comment: I temporarily added "www-data" to "maximilian", changed the primary group of "www-data" to "maximilian" and removed "www-data" from "www-data". Still, after executing `chmod`, the owner stayed root:root.